# How to detect when jQuery mobile opens or close a select menu?

Tags: jquery, mobile, cordova

I'm using phonegap with jQuerymobile,

When using custom menus, I know that is easy to check if the div with the class "ui-selectmenu-screen" has also the class "ui-screen-hidden", but my problem is that i can't trigger this function, i exactly don't know where is the "click" event triggered, when i click on the collapsed select menu, i have tried:

```
$('a.ui-btn').bind('click',function() {
    if (  $('.ui-selectmenu-screen').hasClass("ui-screen-hidden");  ) {
       DO WHAT EVER...
    }
});
```

and many variations of this but is like there is no click event....

Comment: Maybe your element is dynamic so `bind()` won't work. Try using the delegation version of `on()` on the closest static parent

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this issue today and developed the following solution.

```
$("select").change(function() {

    // Ignore events if the interval has already been established
    if (this.interval)
        return false;

    // Self invoking anonymous function to prevent polution of parent scope 
    // in some environments (IE), passes 'this' as element
    (function (element) {

        // Set an interval to watch for the window to close
        element.interval = setInterval((function callback() {

            // Find the widget
            var $widget = $('#'+element.id+'-menu').closest('.ui-selectmenu');

            // If it has been closed DO STUFF and clear the interval
            if ($widget.hasClass('ui-selectmenu-hidden')) {

                // YOUR CODE HERE

                clearInterval(element.interval);

            }

            return callback;
        })(), 1000);

    })(this);

    return false;
});
```

Also worth noting is that if you are re-loading these form elements via ajax you will need to remove the custom widget elements from the DOM prior to inserting the new HTML. Dynamically updating the options would be a more elegant solution but I didn't have that option.

```
$('.ui-selectmenu, .ui-selectmenu-screen, .ui-dialog').remove();
```